# Firebase Auth Google Login Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying the firebase auth to configure google login in my website but it shows error GoogleAuthProvider is not a constructor.

Firebase Config

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/auth";

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
});

export const auth = app.auth();
export default app;
```

Login Function

```
  const googleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  };
```

Its a functional component this button handles the function

```
<button onClick={googleLogin}>
            <img
              style={{ width: "50px", height: "50px" }}
              src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/1200px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png"
              alt=""
            />
          </button>
```

Error I got

```
TypeError: _Login_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.auth.GoogleAuthProvider is not a constructor
```

Can you please tell me why its happening

Comment: Shouldn't you be importing firebase from "firebase/app"?

Comment: You're probably importing your `firebase` app into the file with your `googleLogin` function instead of `import firebase from "firebase/app"`